# Using Nginx as a reverse proxy for a PHP site using Apache with URL rewriting

Tags: apache2, php, proxy, nginx, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use Nginx as a caching reverse proxy for Apache running a PHP site. It's kind of working but the problem comes when trying to rewrite the URL to the Apache setup, it doesn't work as I would have hoped. Here's the setup.

I have a Joomla based PHP site running on Apache, ports 8080 (http) and 44343 (https) - this works fine and there's no problem here. I have removed  the Joomla `.htaccess` file as I assume Nginx will do the rewriting to `index.php` itself and take  care of caching the necessary PHP files.

Joomla rewrites the URL like this `example.com/page1` => `example.com/index.php/page1`

I have Nginx listening on ports 80, 443. Below is the site config

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name    www.example.com
   return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    autoindex off;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    ssl_certificate /example.com/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /example.com/ssl.key;

    root /var/www/site;

    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri;
    }

    # Reverse Proxy and Proxy Cache Configuration
    location ~ \.php {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:44343;

        # Cache configuration
        proxy_cache reverse_cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 3s;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_PHPSESSID;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_PHPSESSID;
        proxy_cache_key "$scheme$host$request_uri";
        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }

    ...
}
```

So this loads the site but no matter what page I go to, it always loads the homepage. It doesn't appear to be sending the `$uri` to `index.php` as expected in the `try_files` part.

The only way I can make this work is by modifying it in the following way:

```
    #location / {
    #   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri;
    #}

    # Reverse Proxy and Proxy Cache Configuration
    location / {
        ...
    }
```

This just sends the entire request to Apache, and I have to bring back the `.htaccess` file which allows Apache to do the rewriting.

The site loads as expected, but the problem is that no PHP files are cached (as checked in /var/cache). So Nginx will have to do the rewriting in order to know which PHP files are cached for which request.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but your upstream app may also require the query string together with the original URI. You could try modifying your default URI as either:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
```

or:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
```

The `nginx` variables are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).